# How can I reference a cell from a different sheet in Excel, only if the sheet exists?

Tags: excel

Basically, I need the cells that are being reference from a sheet that has been deleted to not show "!REF". Is this possible to do only using Excel?

Comment: Use `INDIRECT`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the function `indirect()`, i use this function for myself for refer a sheet that is deleted and recreated.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will try to implement this now and get back to you with my results. I am not so great with Excel. I will probably have to resort to writing a Python script.

Comment: Sorry for the late update, but that still did not work for me. Could you possibly show an example of how you would go about this? Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I figured out my issue. I needed to use IFERROR. Once again, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The indirect function is not a VBA function. Try to use this in formulas.